# Upgrade to Android 7.0 but keep old built-in apps, user apps, etc

Tags: updates, 7.0-nougat

How can I upgrade my Samsung Galaxy S5 from Marshmallow to Nougat without changing the built-in samsung apps, losing user apps, settings, and keeping the Samsung Marshmallow UI? I mean, only updating the kernel and SDK to install newer apps.

Comment: As far as I know Android 6 is the last official version for that phone. The only way to update the OS to a newer version would be to unlock the bootloader and install a custom ROM. As unlocking the bootloader will erase all your data keeping anything is not an option at all.

Comment: In Windows XP, if the hardware is fine you can make a Windows 7 Virtual machine and install new programs there, so could the same possible for android? Setting up an android 7.0 Virtual machine in 6.0?

Comment: Windows is a general purpose OS that works independent of the hardware (can be installed on a large set of hardware systems). Android on the other hand is an embedded system OS which has to be adapted to every hardware you want to install it. This means every Android version on every phone model is unique as it only contains those drivers and services it needs for that specific hardware.